# Equations - Solving for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I have this problem:

$$9x^3 - 18x^2 - 4x + 8 = 0$$

However, I'm not sure how to find the values of $x$. I moved the 8 over and factor out an $x$, but the trinomial it created can't be factored. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Generally speaking, you want the right hand side to be zero. By factoring a polynomial, you're looking to write it as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) = 0.$ Notice that there will be a term there $-abc$ that is not a power of $x$. So, don't move the 8 over -- it won't help.

Cubics are hard to factor. You might not be able to find $a,b,c$ such that they are real numbers. There is a general formula, but it is quite complicated. I'm not sure this problem can be easily solved with simple operations.

Comment: it would easy if you had +8 instead of having -8. Otherwise, Ross's answer is the final one.

Comment: http://www.literka.addr.com/mathcountry/trigonometry/cubic.htm

Comment: You need the rational root theorem - there is one obvious (integer) root, and taking out this factor gives you a quadratic which is easy to factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factor the function.

$9x^3-18x^2-4x+8=9x^2(x-2)-4(x-2)=(x-2)(9x^2-4)=(x-2)(3x-2)(3x+2)$

$(x-2)(3x-2)(3x+2)=0$

$x=2$ or $2/3$ or $-2/3$

Answer (score 8):

The [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) is your friend.  It says all rational roots have numerators that are factors of the constant term and denominators that are factors of the leading term.  Here the numerators can be $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8$ and the denominators can be $1,3,9$.  Not too many to try.  When you find one, you can divide out that root to get a quadratic.  It doesn't always work (as shown with the example with -8 for a constant term) but does sometimes, often in homework.

Comment: I didn't actually. It was + 8 instead of - 8.

Comment: @AndreOseguera: You wrote $-8$ in your primary question. Please take more attention writing the question here. :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wrote it thinking I moved it over to the other side already and got all backwards. Won't happen again. :)

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error method I'm solving this

Divide 9x3−18x2−4x+8 by x-2
reminder is 0 and quotient is 9x2-4x

x-2 = 0   and 9x2-4x = 0

Factorizing 9x2-4x = 0, we get (3x-2)(3x+2) = 0

ie. x = 2, x = 2/3, x = -2/3 are the solutions

(Sorry I'm new to this group and don't know how to write Square of a variable, But answer must be this)

Comment: For formatting, you could look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto  Basically you put $\LaTeX$ between dollar signs.  I'm not sure what this answer contributes beyond what jasoncube wrote.

Comment: Actually I didn't see the answer jason posted. I saw the question and just started solving it. Sorry if it was a duplicate. But thankyou for the link...